# phpredis: BITOP + php implode - not working

Tags: php, redis, implode, phpredis

I have an array

`$array = array("dresses","suits");`

When I try to make BITOP using phpredis

```
$value = implode(",",$array);
$redis->bitOp('AND','color',$value);
echo $redis->bitcount('color');
```

I get 0. Also tried

```
$value = "'".implode("','",$array)."'";
```

with no result. But when I make

```
$redis->bitOp('AND','color','dresses','suits');
echo $redis->bitcount('color');
```

everything is fine. It gives 30 to me

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
$redis->bitOp('AND', 'color', ...$array);
```

Three dots before $array are called "splat operator", introduced in php 5.6

**...$array** means that values of $array are passed to function as variables.